# Generics interface method signature "incorrect"

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I had a hard time thinking of a title for this, so do forgive me.

I have an interface with the following methods:

```
public interface Algorithm<E,F> {
    public Set<? extends Algorithm<E,F>> map(int numPartitions);
    public F reduce(Set<? extends Algorithm<E,F>> partitions);
}
```

and a class implementing `Algorithm` with the following methods:

```
public class LinearSearch<T> implements Algorithm<List<T>, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Set<LinearSearch<T>> map(int numPartitions) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer reduce(Set<LinearSearch<T>> partitions) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now the odd thing is that Eclipse is complaining about the second method, `reduce`.

> `The method reduce(Set<LinearSearch<T>>) of type LinearSearch<T> must override or implement a supertype method.`

This is despite the fact that the `map` method is fine. So where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Overriding Methods and Parameter Types**

On the `reduce` method, the parameter must be a `Set<? extends Algorithm<List<T>,Integer>>`.  It must take any `Set<? extends Algorithm<List<T>,Integer>>`, not just a `Set<LinearSearch<T>>`.  You cannot narrow the parameter type while overriding the method.

The [JLS, Section 8.4.8.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) elaborates on the signatures of overriding methods:

> An instance method m1, declared in class C, overrides another instance method m2, declared in class A iff all of the following are true:
>
> C is a subclass of A.
>
> The signature of m1 is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m2.
>
> Either:
>
> m2 is public, protected, or declared with default access in the same package as C, or
>
> m1 overrides a method m3 (m3 distinct from m1, m3 distinct from m2), such that m3 overrides m2.

Here, "subsignature" refers to the parameter types matching, after type erasure.

**Overriding Methods and Return Types**

But why does the `map` method work?  Because Java allows the developer to narrow the return type of overriding methods on subclasses.

A different [section of the JLS, 8.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5), covers return types in overriding methods:

> Return types may vary among methods that override each other if the return types are reference types. The notion of return-type-substitutability supports covariant returns, that is, the specialization of the return type to a subtype.
>
> A method declaration d1 with return type R1 is return-type-substitutable for another method d2 with return type R2, if and only if the following conditions hold:
>
> If R1 is void then R2 is void.
>
> If R1 is a primitive type, then R2 is identical to R1.
>
> If R1 is a reference type then:
>
> **R1 is either a subtype of R2 or R1 can be converted to a subtype of R2 by unchecked conversion (§5.1.9)**, or
>
> R1 = |R2|

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 2):

Your method header should be as follows

```
public Integer reduce(Set<? extends Algorithm<List<T>, Integer>> partitions)
```

In order to override a method you must use exactly the same parameter types. If not, it is not considered to be the same method.

Note that types `<E,F>` are the parameterized part of that header, so that's where Java gives you some freedom and lets you use the types specified in the class definition.